# Using DATE_ADD with CURRENT_DATE to find things that are happening today in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I'm trying to select my table where I'm looking at things that happened today.

I have it set up as:

```
WHERE date between CURRENT_DATE and DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, 1, DAY);
```

I keep getting the error that `DATE_ADD is not a valid identifier`. I'm using mySQL.

I also tried `DATEADD()` but I don't think that one works in MYSQL.

Comment: mysql 4.0 below is using curdate()

Comment: I don't think you are using MySQL.  You should check the database you are using.  `date_add()` has been part of MySQL for as long as I can remember.

Comment: i just checked and im using SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun Sep 22 16:30:47 2019
Version 19.3.0.0.0
my professor called it mysql but maybe it isnt?? I dont know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `between` for this!  That includes both endpoints.  Instead:

```
where date >= current_date and
      date < current_date + interval 1 day
```

Or:

```
where date >= current_date and
      date < date_add(current_date, interval 1 day)
```

You (presumably) do not want midnight between today and tomorrow.

By the way, if `date` is really just a date and not a `datetime`, the above will work, but you can also write:

```
where date = current_date
```

I strongly discourage you from using:

```
where date(date) = current_date
```

because this prevents an index on `date` from being used.

Sometimes people confuse MySQL and Oracle because Oracle owns both.  In Oracle, this would look like:

```
where date >= current_date and
      date < current_date + interval '1' day
```

That would actually work in MySQL as well.  Or using Oracle-specific features:

```
where date >= trunc(sysdate) and
      date < trunc(sysdate) + interval '1' day
```

Comment: The dates are datetimes so I dont want to use =. I want to get all the times that are between todays date 00:00:00 and 23:59:59

Comment: @SelfHatingLoser . . . That is what the first answer addresses.  Your question is not clear on the type, so I added explanations about that as well.

Comment: when i tried it the way you said with the + interval 1 day it gave me the error "SQL command not properly ended. None of peoples suggestions seem to be working for me. :/

Comment: @SelfHatingLoser . . . It works fine when I try it:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9896940681bd5fef09833ad48020f0a6.

Comment: I ended up doing it like where date>= SYSDATE  and
      date <  SYSDATE + 1;

Comment: @SelfHatingLoser . . . If you use `sysdate`, then you should use `trunc(sysdate)`.

Answer (score 1):

Issue with your code: [`DATE_ADD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) accepts a date as first argument and an interval expression as second argument

Consider:

```
WHERE mydate BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Or you can use [`ADDDATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate), which, as second argument, can accept either an interval or a number of days

```
WHERE mydate BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() AND ADDDATE(CURRENT_DATE(), 1);
```

Note 1: please note that [`CURRENT_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date) is a function. Although MySQL also accepts spelling `CURRENT_DATE` and `CURRENT_DATE()`, I find that that the parentheses make the purpose clearer.

Note 2: as for `DATEADD()`, it just does not exist in MySQL.

Comment: When i do CURRENT_DATE() with the parentheses it gives me the error "missing keyword"

Comment: @SelfHatingLoser: actually, both should work (with or without parentheses), as explained in the documentation (I just modified my answer to be more precise about that). Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I think I'm using version mysqlplus 19.3.0

Answer (score 0):

older MySQL versions you can do like this.

```
where date between curdate() and curdate() + 1;
```

and this is still supported up to this current versions of mySQL.